# Interpolation Function is not saved in notebook

Tags: warning-messages, notebooks, interpolation

I get the following message when an interpolation function is generated as a solution of NDSolve:
[image]

I don't know why this warning is showing and I don't find anywhere where I can consult what this message is about. I have problems when trying to save this function (in case the kernel restarts) and I think it could be due to this.

Comment: The size of the data is beyond some limit.  I don't know what that limit is off hand or whether you can override it.

Comment: You can store the data in a `LocalObject`, or a file with `Save` or `DumpSave`, if you want it available for future sessions.

Answer (score 2):

The limit seems to be given by

```
ElisionsDump`$NotebookAbsoluteStorageLimit
(*  134217728  *)
```

It is derived from the system option:

```
SystemOptions["TypesetOptions"]
(*
{"TypesetOptions" -> {
   "ColorDirectiveSwatches" -> True, 
   "EmbedButtonByteCountLimit" -> 134217728,   (* <-- !!! *)
   "IconicElidedForms" -> True, 
   "InterpretableElidedForms" -> False, 
   "NumericalApproximationForms" -> False, 
   "ParenthesizeScriptBase" -> False, 
   "TransformationFunctionElidedThreshold" -> 4}}
*)
```

You can use `SetSystemOptions[]` to override it.  Storing a great amount of data in a notebook may make the notebook unwieldy to use in the front end of Mathematica.  You are probably better off storing it in a `LocalObject[]` or in the cloud if you can.  The "Store now" button brings up a popup menu that makes it convenient to do so:

[image]

You could also use `DumpSave["file.mx", sol]` to save it to a file.
You can read in a `LocalObject` or a .mx file with `Get[]`.